# Como fazer loops no R

Tags: r, for

Estou trabalhando com dados climáticos e preciso fazer uma análise de limites para cada elemento do meu banco de dados. Preciso fazer loops porque o meu banco de dados é muito grande, mas eu não sei por onde começar.

Uma parte do meu arquivo é esse:

```
dia hora    data    tem_1min    
1   1.0000  01/01/2012  20.463  
1   1.0417  01/01/2012  20.071  
1   1.0833  01/01/2012  19.462  
1   1.1250  01/01/2012  19.4    
1   1.1667  01/01/2012  18.528  
1   1.2083  01/01/2012  18.428  
1   1.2500  01/01/2012  18.411  
1   1.2917  01/01/2012  19.087  
1   1.3333  01/01/2012  20.063  
1   1.3750  01/01/2012  21.393  
1   1.4167  01/01/2012  23.722  
1   1.4583  01/01/2012  23.809  
1   1.5000  01/01/2012  24.49   
1   1.5417  01/01/2012  22.677  
1   1.5833  01/01/2012  22.905  
1   1.6250  01/01/2012  24.373  
1   1.6667  01/01/2012  25.07   
1   1.7083  01/01/2012  23.197  
1   1.7500  01/01/2012  22.631  
1   1.7917  01/01/2012  21.32   
1   1.8333  01/01/2012  20.503  
1   1.8750  01/01/2012  19.583  
1   1.9167  01/01/2012  19.911  
1   1.9583  01/01/2012  19.876
```

Preciso fazer as seguintes analises:
1) Análise de tolerância- se o meu elemento (tem- temperatura) está variando entre 2 a 3 °C de uma hora para outra. Se essa estiver dentro desse limite, preciso atribuir uma nota, no qual 0 significa que está dentro do limite, 1 para variação fora desse limite e 3 para não possui dados (tenho algumas linhas sem dados). Essas notas pode ser substituindo os valores nessa mesma coluna ou criando uma nova.

Comment: Olá Luana! Sua pergunta não fica clara, sugiro descrever o que busca na análise de limites, o porque do loop etc. Também sugiro colocar uma pequena parte da sua base, 1 a 5 dias com 4 a 6 colunas, para que possa ficar claro e reproduzível os resultados.

Comment: será que agora ficou mais claro? !!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há motivo nenhum para usar ciclos `for` ou outros. O R é uma linguagem de programação vetorizada, o que significa que pode processar vetores inteiros de uma só vez. Aqui vai.

Primeiro vou transformar o vetor coluna `data` num objeto de classe `Date`. Não vai ser utilizada mas creio que é um passo que pode ser útil noutras situações e portanto não faz mal fazê-lo já.

```
dados$data <- as.Date(dados$data, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

Depois, criar a coluna com as notas `0`, `1` ou `3`.

```
dif <- c(0, diff(dados$tem_1min))
dados$nota <- as.integer(abs(dif) < 2 | abs(dif) > 3)
dados$nota[is.na(dados$nota)] <- 3L

head(dados, 10)
#   dia   hora       data tem_1min nota
#1    1 1.0000 2012-01-01   20.463    1
#2    1 1.0417 2012-01-01   20.071    1
#3    1 1.0833 2012-01-01   19.462    1
#4    1 1.1250 2012-01-01   19.400    1
#5    1 1.1667 2012-01-01   18.528    1
#6    1 1.2083 2012-01-01   18.428    1
#7    1 1.2500 2012-01-01   18.411    1
#8    1 1.2917 2012-01-01   19.087    1
#9    1 1.3333 2012-01-01   20.063    1
#10   1 1.3750 2012-01-01   21.393    1
```

**Edição.**

Em comentário foi agora pedido o seguinte.

Em cada linha, atribuir o valor `5` quando `tem_1min` estiver entre `0` e `40`, `6` se estiver fora deste intervalo e `7` se não houver dados.

```
inx <- 0 <= dados$tem_1min & dados$tem_1min <= 40
dados$nota2 <- 7L
dados$nota2[inx] <- 5L
dados$nota2[!inx] <- 6L
```

Comment: Você também sabe me informar qual comando eu posso usar para criar uma outra coluna, mas agora eu queria saber se em cada linha da variável tem_1min está dentro de um intervalo que vai de 0 a 40, e da mesma forma que anteriormente quero atribuir notas.

Comment: @LuanaCosta É outra vez a variação de uma linha para a linha seguinte ou é o valor em cada linha? E quais são as notas que correspondem a estar dentro do intervalo e não estar?

Comment: É o valor em cada linha, atribuindo 5 quando dentro do padrão, 6 quando fora do padrão e 7 quando não há dados, o padrão é 0 e 40. Ah! eu testei o código anterior e a nota que está sendo atribuída é somente 1, mesmo possuindo notas 0 e 3.

Comment: @LuanaCosta No resultado da resposta a linha `11` tem `nota` igual a zero, está dentro do padrão. Nenhuma das outras diferenças está entre `2` e `3`.

Comment: @LuanaCosta Feito, veja a edição.

Comment: Eu adaptei esses códigos para o meu banco de dados e não consegui fazer com que aparecesse esse 0, e usei os mesmos códigos que você e isso não aconteceu também. Vou ver o que faço aqui. Muito obrigado @Rui Barradas, você me ajudou muito.

Comment: Barrados, a segunda parte do código está dando erro, será que você pode me ajudar novamente. Quando eu adaptei para os outros elementos dá erro: "not meaningful for factors".       AJUSTE REALIZADO:      
                                                                                                       
 lim_temp <- (-40)<= dados_horas$temp_med & dados_horas$temp_med <= 60
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [lim_temp] <- 5L
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [!lim_temp] <- 6L
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med <- 7L

Comment: @LuanaCosta Isso significa que `temp_med` é de classe `factor`, faça `dados_horas$temp_med <- as.numeric(as.character(dados_horas$temp_med))` antes. E `dados_horas$nota1_temp_med <- 7L` antes das outras duas.

Comment: Testei e está aparecendo agora o seguinte erro: "NAs introduced by coercion", logo apos a primeira linha de comando: dados_horas$temp_med <- as.numeric(as.character(dados_horas$temp_med)).....
lim_temp <- (-40)<= dados_horas$temp_med & dados_horas$temp_med <= 60...
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med <- 7L....
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [lim_temp] <- 0L...
dados_horas$nota1_temp_med [!lim_temp] <- 3L...
table(dados_horas$nota1_temp_med).... (... = nova linha no script)